# C++ lambda, which was specified to capture by value, actually behaves as if it captures by reference

Tags: c++, lambda

Looking at various examples with lambda expressions, I came across unexpected behavior for me. In this code, I expect that the variables captured by value will not change inside the lambda. Code execution shows the opposite. Can someone give an explanation. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Fuu{

public:

    Fuu(int v):m_property(v){}

    void setProperty(int v ){m_property = v;}

    std::function<void(int)> lmbSet {[=](int v){  m_property = v;}};
    std::function<void(char *)> lmbGet {[=](char * v){ cout<< v << " "<< m_property << endl;}};
    std::function<void()> lmb4Static {[=]{  cout<<"static: "<< s_fild << endl;}};

    void call() const {
        lmbGet("test") ;
    }

    static int s_fild ;

    int m_property;
};

int Fuu::s_fild = 10;

int main()
{
    Fuu obj(3);

    obj.call();

    obj.setProperty(5);

    obj.call();//expect 3

    obj.lmbSet(12);

    obj.call(); //expect 3

    obj.lmb4Static();

    Fuu::s_fild = 11;

    obj.lmb4Static(); //expect 10

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture by value only takes copies of local variables (none in your example) and `this` pointer. Capturing `this` by value is equivalent to capturing non-static data members by reference. Static member variables, like globals, are not captured at all - you are accessing them directly instead.

If you actually need to keep a copy of non-local data, you can do it using "generalized capture" syntax which was added in C++14:

```
[m_property=m_property](char * v){ cout<< v << " "<< m_property << endl;}
```

Comment: Also "The implicit capture of *this when the capture default is = is deprecated. (since C++20)" from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: @YakovGalka you probably meant "implicit capture of "`this`", not "`*this`"

Comment: I quoted the sentence from cppreference; you're right that it looks like a type.

Answer (score 3):

That is a common problem.  Common enough that they deprecated the implicit capture of `this` in a lambda with `=` for C++20.  When your code is doing is:

```
std::function<void(int)> lmbSet {[=](int v){  m_property = v;}};
```

It is effectively doing this:

```
std::function<void(int)> lmbSet {[this](int v){  this->m_property = v;}};
```

The lambda captures the `this` pointer by copy, not `m_property` at all.

In general, but formally in C++20, the preferred way to do this would be to explicitly copy `this` (in which case, no `=` is necessary, though you could):

```
std::function<void(int)> lmbSet {[this](int v){  m_property = v;}};
```

To make a copy of the current object and modify that copy, you'd need to dereference `this` (and then the capture is a copy of `*this`) and to modify it, you'd need to mark your lambda `mutable`:

```
std::function<void(int)> lmbSet {[*this](int v) mutable {  m_property = v;}};
```

It doesn't seem very useful, but perhaps that helps explain what's going on.

*[Note: it's not valid to copy `*this` until the construction completes, or it's copying an object before its lifetime starts, and that will result in undefined behavior.]*

Comment: `[*this]` would cause a copy of `lmbSet` before it is initialized. `this` hasn't finished initializing members by the time it would need to be copied.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You are absolutely correct.  I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `[=]` effectively just copies `this` as a pointer. Then, when you access data members in your closure the copy of `this` is dereferenced, and if you modify that member it modifies the original member. If you think about it, it isn't possible that `[=]` copies each member. You would have an infinite recursion of copies as each `lmbSet` would make a new copy of `lmbGet`, which in turn would make a new copy of `lmbSet`.

Note that this solution requires that the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) be applied. If you try to make a copy of an instance of `Fuu`, the captured `this` pointer will copied and point to the original instance and not to the new copy. In general, capturing `this` or pointers to data members in default member initializes should be avoided.